# Logstash filter, if field matches regex not working

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

In my Logstash pipeline I want to apply some operations to a field if it matches a regex. For example I want to filter all `url` fields that start with `JOB:` so after researching I came up with this config:

```
filter {
        grok {
            patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
                  if [url] =~ /^JOB: .*/ {
                       add_field => {
                              "job_type" => "JOB: %{job_type:url}"
                       }
                  }
         }
}
```

But after running `service logstash configtest` I get this error:

```
The given configuration is invalid. Reason: 
Expected one of #, => at line 87, column 7 (byte 3332) after filter {
                        grok {
                                patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
                                if
```

Comment: Then accept the below solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` needs to go out of the `grok` filter, i.e. it must surround the `grok`

```
filter {
    if [url] =~ /^JOB: .*/ {
        grok {
            patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
            match => ["url" => "JOB: %{job_type:job_type}"]
        }
    }
}
```